# control a function pointer in the kernel

Tags: c, pointers, linux-kernel

If I have controlled a function pointer in the kernel pointing to somewhere I want, let's make it point to my own designed function `evil` in the user land.

```
err = writepage(page) //->writepage is a kernel function pointer pointing to a evil in the userland
```

There is only a `printf` in `evil`, will there be kernel panic if the kernel dereferences that function pointer? Since `evil` runs in the kernel mode (correct me if I'm wrong), but kernel does not what `printf` is.

```
int evil() {
   printf("I don't think printf will be executed because evil is executed is kernel mode")
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because malware development

Comment: @MartinJames That is a) not really the case and b) wouldn't even be a reason for a downvote. I'd say this is an attempt at understanding how the OS works, not an promising attempt at writing malware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The kernel never sees "`printf`"; it sees a call to a different address, just like the program doesn't call that function by its name, but sets up registers containing parameters accordingly and calls that function.

That won't work, because the address that the `printf` call points to is relative to the userland process' memory, and doesn't exist in kernel memory.

You have to realize that processes run in a virtual memory of their own -- none of the addresses used in a program need to make sense for a different process.

So you *can't* even just call a function in a userland process; you'd first have to find out where that is in memory as the kernel sees it, and then call it. Of course, it'd then run in kernel mode, but that's not surprising -- no sane OS would allow a userland process to bend internal function calls in that manner.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. According to your explanation, I think the only thing I could do is to use assembly.

Comment: @HuangJie: no. Assembly is no different from any programming language: The kernel doesn't care how your software came to be. there's no way you can make your kernel do something with assembly that you couldn't in e.g. C.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I'm doing research a very old bug of Linux. So what can I trigger with this? I have controlled a function pointer in the kernel. So some shell code? Many thanks.

Comment: if you can just bend around functions that will be called in the kernel, what about pointing it towards something that messes with your system *inside* the kernel? For example, maybe you can modify what is in the registers that would get interpreted as parameters on a function call, and then you'd call something that e.g. gives a specific process a different uid(e.g. 0 for root) or so?

Comment: Really, however, you're lacking the basics of OS theory. I think as a security researcher, you'd need to be the one understanding very precisely how OSes are *supposed* to work before you can understand what happens when they don't. What I'm saying is: read some book on OS design.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and hint. I Really appreciate it.

Comment: One thing I'm really puzzled about is that I have controlled the `write_page` function pointer in `filemap_fdatasync`   [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/filemap.c?v=2.4.37#L602) pointing to my own `evil_writepage` in the user space. And then I use system call `msync`, it will call `filemap_fdatasync`, I can even see the print out message by `printf` in `evil_writepage`! To my understanding, system calls run in kernel mode, so kernel does not know what `printf` is. What's wrong with me :((((